# Why is SET PACKING in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, polynomial-time, packing

I have seen an lot of proves why SET PACKING is NP complete. However, in every prove it states that SET PACKING is clearly in NP. It might be a stupid question, but is not so clear to me. I see that the procedure contains of 2 parts:

1. Choosing a subset of size k from a collection of sets
2. Check whether the chosen subset of size k is mutually disjoint

But why does this take polynomial time? I can see that step 1 takes n steps in the worst case scenario, but I don't know what to do for the second step. How does the Turing machine verify this? And how many steps does this take?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @PålGD sorry, but I know this problem with a slightly different name - this terminology is new for me.

Comment: To check if two sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint...is polytime, right? For every element in $A$ you can simply check if it is in $B$ or not. It takes $|A| \cdot |B|$ time...that is polynomial. So what is the difficulty in proving NP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve such a problem, you should have more of a "programming" point of view rather than a "Turing machine" point of view.

Sure, $\mathsf{NP}$ is defined considering the executing time of a Turing machine, however we, human beings, are not made to think in TM. You could think of it as the same difference between programming in a very low level programming language (like assembler) and a high level language (like python).

To have an idea as to how verify the solution of a Set Packing problem, you could also think of a usefull data structure to ease the verification. Here, I think that using [boolean arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) is the easiest:

- since all subsets are subsets of the same set $S$, consider a bijection between $S$ and $\{1, …, n=|S|\}$ (I will now identify elements of $S$ with integers);
- a subset $T\subseteq S$ can be represented with an array $[t_1, t_2, …, t_n]$ such that $t_i = true$ if $i\in T$ and $t_i = false$ otherwise;
- considering a family $T_1, T_2, …, T_k$ of subsets of $S$, you can consider the following algorithm to verify that they are disjoint:

```
Input: boolean arrays T1, T2, …, Tk of length n
Create T a boolean array containing n false
for i = 1 to k do
    for j = 1 to n do
        if T[j] and Ti[j] then
           return False
        T[j] ← T[j] or Ti[j]
return True
```

The idea is that the array $T$ will keep track of all elements of $\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^k T_i$. If I find an element $j$ is in $T_i$ but I have already found $j$, then there are two subsets that are not disjoint.

The time complexity of the algorithm is $\mathcal{O}(n)$ (creation of $T$) + $\mathcal{O}(nk)$ (loops). It is indeed polynomial in the size of the problem.

Note that you could consider representing $T$ with a boolean array, and $T_1$, …, $T_k$ using a list of contained elements. That would result in a better complexity.

```
Input: integer n, lists T1, T2, …, Tk containing elements between 1 and n
Create T a boolean array containing n false
for i = 1 to k do
    for x in Ti do
        if T[x] then
           return False
        T[x] ← True
return True
```